# Restify static webserver stops working after enabling HTTP basic authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, restify, basic-authentication

I have a working node.js restify server configured to work as a static webserver. Here is the relevant code;

```
var server = restify.createServer({
    name: 'myapp',
    version: '1.0.0'
});

var static_webserver = function (app) {
    app.get(/.*/, restify.serveStatic({
        'directory': 'static', //static html files stored in ../static folder
        'default': 'index.html'
    }));
} //var static_server = function (app)

static_webserver(server);
```

After I enable HTTP Basic authentication to have better security for the other REST APIs, the static webserver stopped working.

This is the code for enabling HTTP Basic authentication.

```
server.use(restify.authorizationParser());
function verifyAuthorizedUser(req, res, next)
{
    var users;

    users = {
        foo: {
            id: 1,
            password: 'bar'
        }
    };

    if (req.username == 'anonymous' || !users[req.username] || req.authorization.basic.password !== users[req.username].password) {
        // Respond with { code: 'NotAuthorized', message: '' }
        next(new restify.NotAuthorizedError());
    } else {
        next();
    }

    next();
}//function verifyAuthorizedUser(req, res, next)

server.use(verifyAuthorizedUser);
```

It seems that after enabling authentication, no web browser was able to visit the static html webpages because authentication is required. How can I disable authentication for the static webserver but enable authentication for the other REST APIs?

Comment: May I know why the downvote? What is wrong with the question? Can someone explain so that I can improve on my questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your nodejs is up to date enough to support [`string.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith):

```
function verifyAuthorizedUser(req, res, next) {
    var path = req.path();
    // check if the path starts with /static/
    if (path.startsWith('/static/')) {
        return next();
    }

    var users;
    users = {
        foo: {
            id: 1,
            password: 'bar'
        }
    };

    if (req.username == 'anonymous' || !users[req.username] || req.authorization.basic.password !== users[req.username].password) {
        // Respond with { code: 'NotAuthorized', message: '' }
        next(new restify.NotAuthorizedError());
    } else {
        next();
    }

    next();
}
```

If you don't have startsWith(), a good old regex will do:

```
if (path.match(/\/static\/.*/)) {
    return next();
}
```